# MassTransit Quick Start App doesn't work

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to learn MassTransit.  I've installed MassTransit.RabbitMQ version 3.3.5 via NuGet.  I've already installed Erlang 18.0* and RabbitMQ 3.6.3 (*Erlang version 19.0 is unstable with RabbitMQ 3.6.3).  I found a "quick start" MassTransit program [here](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html), and after fixing a little typeo, got it to compile.  However, when I execute the program, the published message "YourMessage" is not handled by the handler!  RabbitMQ management plugin UI shows that there is a "test_queue" queue with 1 message in it.  And there it remains, unprocessed.  What is going on here?  I'm running on Windows 7 and the RabbitMQ service is running.

```
using MassTransit;
using System;

namespace MassTransitPOC.Trivial
{
    public class YourMessage
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
            {
                var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });

                sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test_queue", ep =>
                {
                    ep.Handler<YourMessage>(context =>
                    {
                        return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Text}");
                    });
                });
            });

            bus.Start();

            bus.Publish(new YourMessage { Text = "Hi" });

            bus.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got it working by replacing the receive endpoint code from:

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test_queue", ep =>
{
    ep.Handler<YourMessage>(context =>
    {
        return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Text}");
    });
});
```

... to the following ...

```
sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test_queue", ep =>
{
    ep.Handler<YourMessage>(context =>
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Text}"));
    });
}
```

See if that works for you?

(RabbitMQ: 3.6.2 / Erlang: OTP 18)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your code hasn't changed anything except for the style of the llambda expression that makes up the handler; it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the bus.Stop() call is being made too quickly on my machine.  If I add in the following between the .Publish and .Stop, then the message is received.  Without this code though, the published message isn't consumed.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadKey();
```